# PHP - Authentication issues on a Facebook Canvas App using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, facebook, mod-rewrite, facebook-canvas

I have a Facebook Canvas app that works with ids ?id= and I wanted to make the urls look a bit nicer so I added this to my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^u(.*?)\.php$ index.php?id=$1
```

This is the Login url for facebook

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1, 'scope' => 'permissions', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://domain.com/u'.$id.'.php'));
```

So it goes to u123456789.php after authenticating.
Now my problem is that $facebook->getUser(); always returns 0 even if the user has authenticated and allowed the app because of that redirect.

If I redirect to index.php after authenticating it works fine.

I think this is caused by the session or something. Is there any solution to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you didn't give any context as to how $facebook->getUser() is supposed to get its value.  Is it the id parameter?

Comment: The id is something else, the code is like this 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => $appid,
  'secret' => $secret,
  'cookie' => true
));


// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;

  }
}

Comment: I guess I am still failing to see the connection between your rewrite rule and your Facebook class if the id parameter is not related to the user.

Comment: It is not about the id but about the user variable always being 0 when redirecting to u123456.php while it works with index.php

Comment: So how does the code in u123456789.php differ from that in index.php?